# How to create a .Trash folder on a Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, recycle-bin

I recently replaced the internal hard drive on my iMac with an SSD, and because it didn't have as much storage as the hard drive it replaced, I elected to move my user account off the drive and on to an external hard drive.

All is well, except that for some reason my root user account doesn't contain a trash folder, so if I want to send anything to the trash I get a popup stating "This item will be deleted immediately. You can’t undo this action."

Having read other posts, and having typed various suggested solutions into a Terminal window, none of them have worked, and I'm now at a loss to know what to try next.

I thought that...

```
mkdir ~/.Trash
```

...would work, but I get an 'Operation not permitted' message.
I've also tried...

```
sudo mkdir ~/.Trash
```

...but I get the same message.

Clearly I'm just scrabbling around in the dark (what, you couldn't tell?!), so I thought I'd ask :)

Many thanks,
Tony.

Comment: First, are you actually using the root user account, and moving it, or just a regular account? Using and/or messing with the root account is generally a dangerous idea, and I'd recommend against it. Second, it sounds like there's something weird with the permissions and/or status of the new home folder or the disk it's on. What do `ls -leO@d ~` and `mount` list?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gordon. I moved the root user account to the external drive, following instructions I found online, and apart from this trash issue it all seems perfectly fine.
I'll provide the results from those commands you suggested in separate comments below...

Comment: `ls -leO@d ~` gives:  
`drwxr-xr-x@ 52 <account name>  staff  uchg 1768  8 Jun 19:13 /Volumes/User Data/<account name>`
com.apple.finder.copy.checkpoint#N    8 
com.apple.finder.copy.source.inode#N    8 
com.apple.finder.copy.source.volumeuuid#N   36 
com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot   50 
com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot   50

Comment: `mount` gives:  

/dev/disk1s1 on / (apfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s4 on /private/var/vm (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/User Data (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
/dev/disk3s2 on /Volumes/Time Machine (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls -leO@d ~` lists the "uchg" flag, which means that your home folder is locked against changes (uchg = User-level lock against CHanGes). You can unlock it by either Getting Info on it in the Finder and unchecking the Locked box, or with the command `chflags nouchg ~`.

Comment: [Should one advise on off topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Comment: Wow, thanks Gordon, that's the perfect solution. I've now created the Trash folder and it's working great. I knew if I asked the question, there'd be someone who'd be willing and able to help! Thanks again.